# Custom icon not showing on desktop (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, icons, .desktop

Today I created a link to a folder, like so:
[image: link_creation]

Then, I looked up the location of the original icon (See the red M below the link I just created). Then I right clicked the "Link to MEGA", and clicked on the icon.

I navigated to the original icon location, and changed the "Link to MEGA" icon (The plain Ubuntu folder) to the original MEGA icon, like so:
[image: icon_selection]

As is seen in the screenshot this seems to be working fine! However, when I then drag and drop this Link to the Desktop folder, **the icon does not display properly on my desktop** (As is seen below (Excuse me for my crappy paint skills haha)

[image]

**Does anyone know why this is happening and how do I fix it?**

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, the icons are shown on the desktop by an extension (Desktop Icons) and not by Nautilus (the file manager). This is probably an issue of the extension. If you wish, you may create a new issue in the [extension's GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons/-/issues).